# ¿Lleva "como" tilde en "verás como todo va bien"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, ortografía, acentuación, adverbios

Muchas veces me entra la duda de si en la oración

> Verás como todo va bien.

la palabra "como" lleva o no tilde. Por la entonación que le suelo dar a la frase diría que no, pero si la analizo gramaticalmente mi intuición me dice que sí. Y luego resulta que me encuentro esta definición en el diccionario:

> **[como<sup>2</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9xWxEd9)**
>
> ```
> Del lat. quomŏdo.
> Puede escribirse con acento en acep. 6.
> ```
>
> 6. adv. relat. Algún modo en que o ningún modo en que. U. sin antecedente expreso, generalmente con los verbos *tener* y *haber*. *No tenía como escribirlo.*

¿Al final resulta que puedo escribirlo de cualquiera de las dos formas, con tilde y sin tilde? ¿Encaja este uso de "como" con la mencionada acepción 6?

Comment: yo usaría de reemplazo la palabra forma o manera a esa definición: No tenía *manera* escribirlo. En ese caso, tu frase sería: Verás *la manera* todo va bien... pero se ve HORRIBLE (perdón por las mayúsculas). No sé si es el mejor sinónimo o remplazo, pero ya dirás si puede aplicar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iba a confirmar tu suposición pero mira lo que aparece en la acepción 15

> [**como**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9xWxEd9)
>
> 15. conj. desus. Sustituía a **que** para introducir una subordinada. *Sabrás como hemos llegado sin novedad*. U. actualmente solo con ciertos verbos. *Sal con ellos y **verás como lo pasas muy bien***.

Creo que tu frase "Verás como todo va bien" coincide en estructura con la señalada en negrita.

> Verás como todo va bien = Verás **que** todo va bien.

Comment: Vaya, pues sí que encaja, ¡bien visto!

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la acepción que aplica en este caso es la número 6 de [cómo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9xX6XpW):

> **6.** adv. excl. De qué modo, de qué manera. *¡Cómo vive!*

Es decir,

> Verás *de qué manera* todo va bien.

La acepción 6 de *como* (sin tilde) no concuerda con el significado del ejemplo; lo que se le está diciendo al oyente es que ya verá ¡de qué manera! las cosas irán bien. El uso es paralelo al de otros adverbios exclamativos:

> Verás cuántos regalos te traeré.
>   Verás qué bien te va.
>   Verás quién te está esperando en casa.

Comment: Curioso, a mí me encajaba la acepción 6 de "como" porque interpretaba la frase como "verás que, de algún modo, todo va bien". ¿Cambiarías la forma de interpretar la frase si fuera "verás cómo todo VA A IR bien"?